# How to update Custom Fields after File Upload using SenseNet dotnet client

Tags: sensenet

Is there a way I can update my custom fields after a file upload (and having obtained the new content Id) using the sn-client-dotnet?
I am targeting a SN 7 installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should reload the content, modify the field and call & await *saveAsync()*

```
var uploadedDocument = await Content.LoadAsync(uploadedDocId);
uploadedDocument["CustomFieldName"] = someValue;
await uploadedDocument.SaveAsync();
```

You can find some detailed examples [here](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Client_library)